# C# Parallel.For to create array: OK to put lock() on the array?

Tags: c#, performance, locking, task-parallel-library

I have a time-consuming static C# method for creating an array (of `double`:s) and have therefore parallelized the operation.

Since I am creating the array before entering the loop and not tampering with its reference after that, I am thinking that it should be sufficient to `lock` the array itself while updating it within the parallel loop.

Is it OK to `lock` on the array itself or would I potentially face some performance or deadlock problems with this approach? Is it better to create a separate `lock` variable to put the lock on?

Here is some sample code to illustrate:

```
static double[] CreateArray(int mn, int n)
{
  var localLock = new object();    // Necessary?
  var array = new double[mn];

  Parallel.For(0, n, i =>
  {
    ... lengthy operation ...

    lock (array)    // or is 'lock (localLock)' required?
    {
      UpdatePartOfArray(array);
    }
  });

  return array;
}
```

Comment: If at any point during the "...lengthy operation..." code you are reading from the array, then you (might) have a race condition.

Comment: Why do you need to lock the array? Do the parallel operations touch the *same* elements in the array? If so, how much overlap is there between ops?

Comment: @PaulPhillips Thanks, good point! In my current scenario I do not read from the array, but I might in other scenarios. Obviously a good reason to lock the local variable then.

Comment: It would only be a race condition if you're reading an array value another thread could potentially change.  If each iteration is totally isolated from the others (only reads and writes from one index, for instance, and each iteration gets a unique index) then there would be no problem.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever My main reason for locking the array is I wouldn't need to create a dedicated lock variable and thus keep the code a tiny little bit cleaner :-) In my current scenario the parallel operations do _not_ touch the same elements, but in other scenarios they might. So I think Paul's comment above is very important in the general sense.

Comment: I believe Damien is asking why the need to lock at all, not why you want to use that particular variable to lock on.

Comment: If your operations *are* touching the same elements, then (in the general case) more co-ordination is needed than a simple lock, since you can have race conditions, etc. If there is *no* overlap, then *no* locking is necessary.

Comment: OK, I realize that now after reading Marc's answer. Many thanks, both Damien and Paul, very clarifying comments.

Comment: If you put the entire loop body in a lock in the general case, that would work. But it would defeat the point of using a parallel foreach loop to do that. Not all problems benefit equally from threading

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the `array` here is a reference type, isn't reassigned during the operations, and isn't exposed elsewhere yet (where some *other* code could lock it), yes, it can suffice as the lock object itself. However, if the updates are to different parts of the array, i.e.

```
array[i] = ... // i is separate
```

then there is no need to lock anything.

Comment: Many thanks for a very clarifying answer, Mark. In my specific scenario I am using Array.Copy() to write data to `array`, but each `i` thread touches its own "slot" of `array`. Given this, is it still OK to skip locking altogether?

Comment: @AndersGustafsson I can't think of any reason that would be a problem.